# Can anyone tell me what "dataviz" is?

Tags: silverlight, charts

[Change Silverlight Chart Legend Item Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917031/change-silverlight-chart-legend-item-layout)

Can anyone please tell me what the `dataviz` component is in the following code (from the linked question)

```
<dataviz:Legend x:Name="Legend" Header="{TemplateBinding LegendTitle}" Style="{TemplateBinding LegendStyle}" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

I get the following error when I try to use it:

> The type 'dataviz:Title' was not
>   found. Verify that you are not missing
>   an assembly reference and that all
>   referenced assemblies have been built

Comment: Have you tried google? I found http://www.dataviz.com

Comment: You'll have to ask the author, maybe as a comment in that question. It is a namespace prefix, which means you need to have a namespace declaration somewhere. ... Looking through your other posts, you seem to know how to write English. What happened?

Comment: It's the only reference to dataviz the search engine shows up. Perhaps the OP of the question you linked to was creating a web site for mobile devices. As Martinho Fernandes says, posting a comment on the original question might get you the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dataviz: was a common xml namespace alias used for the silverlight toolkit data visualisation namespce.  This was for Silverlight 3 version at the time when libraries weren't able to define their own XML namespaces.

The .NET namespace System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization would be mapped to the prefix `dataviz` like this:-

```
xmlns:dataviz="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

With Silverlight 4 enabling libraries to define their own schema url to cover a whole range of .NET namespaces things changed to this:-

```
 xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
```

This xmlns space covers most objects that you might want to include in Xaml (not just the charting stuff).  The older style still works but generally in Silverlight 4 you only need this single alias to refer to anything in you need from the toolkit.