# Customizing the styles of Piechart silverLight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts, windows-phone

I am working on Windows Phone 8 and  have looked Mango for using Charts, but since we cannot modify or customize i have switched to Charts given by silverlight.

Here is the link:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/wp7/article.php/c20199/How-to-Create-Charts--Graphs-in-Your-Windows-Phone-Application.htm

I am trying to customize the following things:

1) Legends to the bottom of the chart and it should be in one layout only.

2) Click on pie chart slice get the values.

3) Display the slice value above the corresponding slice.

4) Legends text color to black.

5) Change the default slice colors.

I have searched for customizing things  but i am not able to find any way that i can do it.

Here is the XAMl code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <charting:Chart x:Name="MyPieSeriesChart">
                <charting:PieSeries Name="PieChart" 
                                    Tap="PieChart_Tap"
                                    IndependentValuePath="X" 
                                    DependentValuePath="Y" />
            </charting:Chart>
        </Grid>
```

.CS code:

```
this.MyPieSeriesChart.DataContext = new Point[] { new Point(0, 10), new Point(1, 10), new Point(2, 10) };
        }
```

Comment: You have too many questions in your post. Also some of them have been already answered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917031/change-silverlight-chart-legend-item-layout; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764608/silverlight-charting-pie-chart-show-a-dependent-value-on-the-chart; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618581/silverlight-4-chart-toolkit-color-set/5626435#5626435

Comment: @vorrtex thanks for the pointers i will check them